# How do I stop negative numbers and error message: " Failure at t=3.562559e+03. Unable to meet integration tolerances

Tags: matlab, ode

I am using 8 ODEs in Matlab to simulate the effect of asymptomatic infections in the epidemiology of a vector borne disease. Searching the parameter space under certain settings produces negative numbers for the human population and the following warning in the command consol:

"Warning: Failure at t=3.562559e+03. Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (7.275958e-12) at time t. > In ode45 at 308 In Mosquito_Framework_2_human_plots at 79"

Is there some setting I could put the solver on to get rid of the problem. The current solver is ode45 under 'RelTol', 1e-6 option.

The following code produces the negative human population and warning message:

```
function [t,Sh,Ah,Ih,Rh,Se,Sv,Iv] = Mosquito_Framework_2_human_plots(betaI,betaV,c,...
theta,d,muh,p,muv,omega,epsilon,Sh0,Ah0,Ih0,Rh0,Sv0,Ev0,Iv0,MaxTime)

% Sets up default parameters if necessary.
if nargin ~= 18
    disp('defaults')
    %displays message default to say simulation is using defaults if not
    %enouth argumants is given
   betaI = (0.3+1)/2*(0.1+0.75)/2;
   betaV = (0.3+1)/2*(0.5+1)/2;
   c=1;
   theta=8;
   d=0.25;
   muh=1/(60*365.0);
   p=0.9;
   muv=1/6;
   omega=1/11;
   epsilon=1/((8+12)/2);
   Sh0=(1e6)-1;
   Ah0=1;
   Ih0=0;
   Rh0=0;
   Sv0=9.5e6;
   Ev0=0;
   Iv0=0;
   MaxTime=10*(365);
end

gammaI=1/theta;
gammaA=1/(d*theta);
betaA=c*betaI;
Nh0=Sh0+Ah0+Ih0+Rh0;
Nv0=Sv0+Ev0+Iv0; 
Se0=Nv0*(muv/omega);

 % Checks all the parameters are valid
 if Sh0<=0 
     error('Initial level of susceptibles (%g) is less than or equal to  zero',Sh0);
 end

if Ah0+Ih0<=0 
     error('Initial level of infecteds (%g) is less than or equal to zero',Ah0+Ih0);
end

if betaA+betaI<=0  
    error('Transmission rate betaA+betaI (%g) is less than or equal to zero',betaA+beta);
end

if betaV<=0  
    error('Transmission rate betaV (%g) is less than or equal to zero',betaA+beta);
end

if gammaA+gammaI<=0 
     error('Recovery rate gammaA+gammaI (%g) is less than or equal to zero',gammaA+gammaI);
end

if muh<=0 
    error('Death and birth rate gamma (%g) is less than or equal to zero',muh);
end

if MaxTime<=0 
    error('Maximum run time (%g) is less than or equal to zero',MaxTime);
end

if Sh0+Ah0+Ih0>Nh0
warning('Initial level of susceptibles+infecteds (%g+%g=%g) is greater than human population size (%g)'...
,Sh0,Ah0,Ih0,Sh0+Ah0+Ih0,Nh0);
end

if Sv0+Ev0+Iv0>Nv0
warning('Initial level of susceptibles+infecteds (%g+%g=%g) is greater than mosquito population size (%g)'...
,Sv0,Ev0,Iv0,Sv0+Ev0+Iv0,Nv0);
end

Sh=Sh0; Ah=Ah0; Ih=Ih0; Rh=Rh0; Se=Se0; Sv=Sv0; Ev=Ev0; Iv=Iv0;

% The main iteration 
options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-6);
[t, pop]=ode45(@Diff_Framework_1,[0 MaxTime],[Sh Ah Ih Rh Se Sv Ev Iv],options,...
    [betaA betaI betaV gammaA gammaI muh p muv omega epsilon]);

Sh=pop(:,1); Ah=pop(:,2); Ih=pop(:,3); Rh=pop(:,4); Se=pop(:,5); Sv=pop(:,6); Ev=pop(:,7); Iv=pop(:,8);

%plot the graphs with scaled colours
plot(t,Ah,'Color',[250/255,228/255,32/255],'LineWidth',1.4);
hold on
%hold on makes matlab plot to the same plot.
plot(t,Ih,'-r','LineWidth',1)
set(gca, 'FontSize', 14)
xlabel('Time in Days','FontSize',18);
ylabel('Human Population','FontSize',18);
% ylim([0,1e5])
name = strcat('Vector_dep_M2@_c=',num2str(c),'_d=',num2str(d),'_p=',num2str(p));
Human_pop_plot_name = strcat('Human_pop_',name,'.fig');
savefig(Human_pop_plot_name);
hold off
%hold off stops matlab ploting to the same plot.
%Saves graph
%creates string based around parameters used called dataset_name 

Both_pops_csv_names = strcat('Both_pops_',name,'.csv');

Both_pops_csv = dataset({t,'Time_in_Days'},{Sh+Ah+Ih+Rh,'Total_Human_Population'},...
{Sh,'Susceptibles_Humans'},{Ah,'Asymptomatic_Humans'},{Ih,'Symptomatic_Humans'},...
{Rh,'Recovered_Humans'},{Se+Sv+Ev+Iv,'Total_Mosquito_Population'},...
{Sv+Ev+Iv,'Total_Adult_Mosquito_Population'},{Se,'Pre_Adult_Mosquito_Population'},...
    {Sv,'Susceptible_Mosquito_Population'},     {Ev,'Incubating_Mosquito_Population'},...
    {Iv,'Infectious_Mosquito_Population'});
%
export(Both_pops_csv,'File',Both_pops_csv_names,'Delimiter',',')
%creats csv file of outputs



% Calculates the differential rates used in the integration.
function dPop=Diff_Framework_1(t,pop, parameter)

betaA=parameter(1); betaI=parameter(2); betaV=parameter(3); gammaA=parameter(4);... 
    gammaI=parameter(5); muh=parameter(6); p=parameter(7); muv=parameter(8); ...
    omega=parameter(9); epsilon=parameter(10);

Sh=pop(1); Ah=pop(2); Ih=pop(3); Rh=pop(4); Nh=Sh+Ah+Ih+Rh; ...
    Se=pop(5); Sv=pop(6); Ev=pop(7); Iv=pop(8); Nv=Sv+Ev+Iv; 

dPop=zeros(8,1);

dPop(1)= muh*Nh - Sh/Nh*(betaV*Iv) - muh*Sh;
dPop(2)= (1-p)*Sh/Nh*(betaV*Iv)-(gammaA+muh)*Ah;
dPop(3)= p*Sh/Nh*(betaV*Iv) - (gammaI+muh)*Ih;
dPop(4)= gammaA*Ah+gammaI*Ih - muh*Rh;
dPop(5)= muv*Nv - omega*Se;
dPop(6)= omega*Se - (Sv*betaA*Ah/Nh + Sv*betaI*Ih/Nh) - muv*Sv;
dPop(7)= (Sv*betaA*Ah/Nh + Sv*betaI*Ih/Nh) - epsilon*Ev - muv*Ev;
dPop(8)= epsilon*Ev - muv*Iv;
```

Comment: I suggest providing a minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue.  For instance, you can remove all the code that deals with postprocessing (plotting, writiing files, etc.) and error checking.  Then it will be easier for others to see the essential problem and help you.

Comment: Also, please write down (in latex) the system of equations that you mean to solve.

Comment: Do you have a proof that the true solution exists and is non-negative for those parameter values?  If not, you shouldn't hope for `ode45` to save you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest plotting the eight solutions up to the point where
`ode45` can no longer obtain a converged solution (t=3562).
In my experience, the error message you site is usually caused by
one of the solutions going to positive or negative infinity.
Looking at the behavior of the solutions prior to convergence
failure may help you identify a problem with the equations
themselves or an error in coding them with MATLAB.

A less common problem is the value of a solution becoming large
but not infinite and the ode solver not able to reach the required
convergence tolerance. In this case, you can make `AbsTol` and/or `RelTol` larger (say one or two orders of magnitude) and obtain a converged solution.